# Are F# Async.Parallel results guaranteed to be in order?

Tags: f#, f#-async

Are the results from F#'s Async.Parallel operation guaranteed to arrive in the order jobs were submitted? My sample code returns the results in order, but I can't find any mention in the MSDN docs, or the F# spec, assuring this **must** be the case -- that it's not a coincidence.

Here is my sample code:

```
let r = System.Random()
Async.Parallel [
    for i in 0..10 ->
        async {
            let rand_num = r.Next(10)
            do! Async.Sleep(rand_num)  (* Simulate jobs taking a variable amount of time *)
            printfn "%i %i" i rand_num
            return i
        }
] 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%A"
```

And here's the output.

```
0 0
5 1
4 1
3 3
10 6
9 4
7 5
2 5
1 5
8 7
6 9
[|0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
```

You can see that, in this run, the async functions complete in indeterminate order, yet the resulting array is sorted. Is this behavior guaranteed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the moment, the source of the function is written so that this guarantee is enforced.  Looking at [control.fs around line #1300](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/6ac6318858da25fe4f1d4728901c5824e9f3bf3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1387) for the definition, we can see the function that puts the results into the output array is

```
let recordSuccess i res = 
    results.[i] <- res;
    finishTask(Interlocked.Decrement count)
```

this function is called in this segment

```
 tasks |> Array.iteri (fun i p ->
     queueAsync
         innerCTS.Token
         // on success, record the result
         (fun res -> recordSuccess i res)
```

where `tasks` has the original tasks in sorted order.  This guarantees that the output list is in the same order as the input.

**UPDATE**

The spec at least seems to imply that the order is fixed - it contains this code:

```
let rec fib x = if x < 2 then 1 else fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)

let fibs = 
    Async.Parallel [ for i in 0..40 -> async { return fib(i) } ]
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

printfn "The Fibonacci numbers are %A" fibs //I changed this line to be accurate

System.Console.ReadKey(true)
```

If the spec didn't guarantee the output order, this code would be incorrect.

Comment: This reminds me of the fact that an integer's `GetHashCode` method simply returns the integer. It's an implementation detail, as opposed to a spec requirement. I would recommend not depending upon that behavior.

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson - I did some digging and the spec seems to at least imply that the output order is guaranteed

Comment: The code has been rewritten in recent times, and IMO remains pretty unambiguous - the impl rests on each independent execution being able to plug their result into the result slot in the array based on their position in the input (which is converted to an array at the outset)